# DongFangInput keeps installing

Tags: windows

have an application that keeps reinstalling itself even after uninstall. It's an app that helps you type in chinese characters. As you can see from the format of this message that it messes with my typing.

Can anyone please help?

PS:Ｉdont even know how to at least turn it off because everything is in chinese.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem since last Saturday (26/4).

I used unlocker as recommended by another website to remove the application.  But my `alt+shift` and `Window+space` hot keys are both not working anymore. So I restored window back to a previous restore point for restoring the hot keys. 
However, after a while the application reinstalled back.

I tried unhackme but the application reinstall after a few reboot.  For the passed 1 week I've been fighting with this application.

On the 30/4, I was thinking whether to refresh my windows, suddenly I realised that I had copy an excel file from my client on 25/4.  His computer same having the same problem.  So I tried to delete the said excel file but it can't be deleted.  So I use unlocker to delete the folder storing the excel file. than I use unhackme to remove all file/program related to Dongfanginput, use unlocker to delete the folder at program folder, restore window to a previous restore point.  My computer is running smoothly for pass 2 days and hoping that the problem wouldn't come back again.  (sorry for my poor English)